# values of $t \in\mathbb R$ the matrix is not invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For which values of $t \in\mathbb R$ the matrix is not invertible ?

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos t &  - \sin t   \\
\sin t  &   \cos t 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

well computing the determinant we know that the determinant of this matrix is $1$,i.e, is invertible , i´m confused with this question, some help please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the determinant is $1$ regardless of the value of $t$, and since matrices with determinant $1$ are invertible, it follows that for all values of $t\in\mathbb R$, this matrix is invertible.  The set $\{t\in\mathbb R : \text{This is not invertible}\}$ is $\varnothing$.

Answer (score 4):

The determinant, $$\Delta=\cos(t)[\cos(t)]-[-\sin(t)][\sin(t)]\equiv \overbrace{\cos^2(t)+\sin^2(t)\equiv1}^{\text{the famous Pythagorean trig. identity}} \neq0,$$ so there are **no** values of $t$ for which the determinant is 0, so the matrix is invertible **for all** $t$ (recall that a matrix is invertible iff its determinant is nonzero).

Answer (score 4):

Geometrically, this matrix just represents a rotation by angle $t$ in the plane so it is clearly invertible.  In fact, its inverse is the same matrix with $t$ replaced by $-t$.

Answer (score 3):

For all values $t \in \emptyset$.

Your matrix represents a rotation in 2D-space. The rectangular coordinate system with base vectors
$$
e_x = \left[
\begin{matrix}
1 \\
0
\end{matrix}
\right], 
e_y = \left[
\begin{matrix}
0 \\
1
\end{matrix}
\right] 
$$

is rotated by $R$ into

$$
e_x' = R e_x = \left[
\begin{matrix}
\cos t \\
\sin t
\end{matrix}
\right], 
e_y' = R e_y = \left[
\begin{matrix}
-\sin t \\
\cos t
\end{matrix}
\right] 
$$

That is why that matrix is probably called $R$ by the way.

And for every rotation of angle $t$, the inverse rotation of angle $-t$ is well-defined. That is why the solution set is empty.

A more algebraic way is to investigate the determinant of the matrix. If it is not zero, the matrix can be inverted. Here your determinant is $1$, independent from $t$.

It turns out that the rotations are the linear mappings with determinant $1$.